# RuntimeError: Unsupported primitive of type: PriorBoxClustered name: fc7_mbox_priorbox

Tags: python, pycharm, openvino

I am trying to run the face_recognition_demo.py from the PyCharm using the openvino library which I installed as follows:

```
conda install openvino-ie4py -c openvino
```

Then I try to run the face_recognition_demo.py script using the following command:

`python face_recognition_demo.py -m_fd C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\OpenVinoStreamlit\face-detection-retail-0004.xml
 -m_lm C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\OpenVinoStreamlit\landmarks-regression-retail-0009.xml -m_reid C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\OpenVinoStreamlit\face-reidentification-retail-00
95.xml --verbose -fg "C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\OpenVinoStreamlit\faces_gallery"`

After running this command, I get the following error:

```
[ DEBUG ] 2020-05-18 16:59:54,768 Namespace(allow_grow=False, cpu_lib='', crop_height=0, crop_width=0, d_fd='CPU', d_lm='CPU', d_reid='CPU', exp_r_fd=1.15, fd_input_height=0, fd_input_width
=0, fg='C:\\Users\\ShraddhaM\\PycharmProjects\\OpenVinoStreamlit\\faces_gallery', gpu_lib='', input='0', m_fd='C:\\Users\\ShraddhaM\\PycharmProjects\\OpenVinoStreamlit\\face-detection-retai
l-0004.xml', m_lm='C:\\Users\\ShraddhaM\\PycharmProjects\\OpenVinoStreamlit\\landmarks-regression-retail-0009.xml', m_reid='C:\\Users\\ShraddhaM\\PycharmProjects\\OpenVinoStreamlit\\face-re
identification-retail-0095.xml', match_algo='HUNGARIAN', no_show=False, output='', perf_stats=False, run_detector=False, t_fd=0.6, t_id=0.3, timelapse=False, verbose=True)
[ INFO ] 2020-05-18 16:59:54,788 Loading models
[ INFO ] 2020-05-18 16:59:54,789 Loading the model from 'C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\OpenVinoStreamlit\face-detection-retail-0004.xml'
[ INFO ] 2020-05-18 16:59:54,840 Model is loaded
[ INFO ] 2020-05-18 16:59:54,840 Loading the model from 'C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\OpenVinoStreamlit\landmarks-regression-retail-0009.xml'
[ INFO ] 2020-05-18 16:59:54,849 Model is loaded
[ INFO ] 2020-05-18 16:59:54,849 Loading the model from 'C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\OpenVinoStreamlit\face-reidentification-retail-0095.xml'
[ INFO ] 2020-05-18 16:59:54,873 Model is loaded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recognition_demo.py", line 446, in <module>
    main()
  File "face_recognition_demo.py", line 441, in main
    visualizer = Visualizer(args)
  File "face_recognition_demo.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.frame_processor = FrameProcessor(args)
  File "face_recognition_demo.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.face_detector.deploy(args.d_fd, context)
  File "C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\OpenVinoStreamlit\ie_module.py", line 75, in deploy
    self.model, device, self.max_requests)
  File "C:\Users\ShraddhaM\PycharmProjects\OpenVinoStreamlit\ie_module.py", line 57, in deploy_model
    return self.ie_core.load_network(model, device, config=config, num_requests=max_requests)
  File "ie_api.pyx", line 85, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IECore.load_network
  File "ie_api.pyx", line 92, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IECore.load_network
RuntimeError: Unsupported primitive of type: PriorBoxClustered name: fc7_mbox_priorbox
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Following are the details of my system:

```
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit 
Python version: `Python 3.7.7 [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`
PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4
cv2 version: 4.2.0
openvino toolkit 2020.2.117.
CPU Device
```

Comment: Which version of OpenVINO do you use? Which type of device (CPU, GPU, MYRIAD, etc) do you use?

Comment: openvino toolkit 2020.2.117. CPU device.

Comment: Hm.. Looks like something wrong with your environment. OpenVINO 2020.2.117 is built against OpenCV 4.3.0 but you said that you use 4.2.0. Please execute the following commands to make sure that you have up-to-date packages: `conda update --all; conda install openvino-ie4py -c openvino; conda install opencv` and try again.

Comment: I performed the above steps, but the version of opencv is not getting updated. Can you please guide me to update the opencv version?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try starting with a fresh environment and trying using the latest OpenVINO release (2021.4.1)?

```
conda create --name py37 python=3.7
conda activate py37
conda update --all
conda install openvino-ie4py -c intel
```